# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in Firebase Function after upgrading to Node 10

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I recently got warnings that Node 8 has been deprecated for Cloud Functions for Firebase. I updated to Node 10 but then I started getting this error even before the function is invoked and the function is not executed. On reverting back to Node 8 fixes the problem. I am not sure how to debug this problem to get more information.

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at dataConstructor (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/database.js:137:85)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:119:34)
    at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:151:20)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:198:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

The error logs are in the functions console log as shown below:
[image]

I have a bunch of Cloud Functions and all of them are failing. I have posting implementation for one of them which has the least amount of code.

```js
exports.isUserRunningMinimumVersion = functions.database
  .ref('/tasks/isUserRunningMinimumVersion/{taskId}')
  .onCreate((taskSnapshot, context) => {
    if (!taskSnapshot.exists()) {
      return
    }
    const task = taskSnapshot.val()

    invariant(
      task.hasOwnProperty('version'),
      "isUserRunningMinimumVersion task doesn't contain required fields [version]"
    )

    let promise
    if (semver.lt(task.version, GlobalConfig.minSupportedVersion)) {
      promise = ref.child('taskResults/' + context.params.taskId).set({
        status: 'success',
        result: {
          userIsRunningMinimumVersion: false,
        },
      })
    } else {
      promise = ref.child('taskResults/' + context.params.taskId).set({
        status: 'success',
        result: {
          userIsRunningMinimumVersion: true,
        },
      })
    }

    return promise.then(() => {
      return ref
        .child('/tasks/isUserRunningMinimumVersion/' + context.params.taskId)
        .remove()
    })
  })
```

Below is my package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/node": "^5.11.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.620.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "child-process-promise": "^2.2.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.3.1",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.2",
    "googleapis": "^41.0.1",
    "i18n-js": "^3.2.2",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mkdirp-promise": "^5.0.1",
    "nexmo": "^2.4.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.2.1",
    "npm": "^6.13.6",
    "semver": "^6.1.1",
    "useragent": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Please share how to fix this problem.

Comment: Please share the entire code of your Cloud Function as well as your `package.json` file.

Comment: Please also be clear about where you are seeing this message.  Is it during deployment? Or in the functions console log?  Provide the full steps to reproduce this so anyone can see it for themselves.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am getting the same error!? My package.json file is as follows `{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^7.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.3.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^6.10.0"
  },
  "private": true
}`

Comment: @RenaudTarnec have added the required information. Thanks.

Comment: @VarunGupta see the response from Doug... it fixed my issue, it would seem ur firebase-functions is old as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your firebase-functions module is very old.  The latest version is 3.8.0.  Upgrade it:

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest
```

Comment: can you assist with this as well? I am getting the following warning `Accessing deprecated metadata server endpoint at "/computeMetadata/v1beta1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" from user-agent ""` Do you know what I can do to resolve!?

Comment: @DougStevenson I have a follow-up question for this. This happened on the production setup for my app and I was unaware of it till some users reported some issues with the app. Is there a way to configure alerting with firebase functions for such failures? This error happened even before the function code was invoked due to which such errors are not caught by Sentry either.

Answer (score 0):

@doug_stephenson was right on.

I _ *thought I had* _ updated my firebase-functions module (3.8.0) and still had this issue.  I had to downgrade my functions node engine to 8.

Then I realized you still have to update the firebase-function module within the functions directory

```
cd functions
npm install firebase-functions@latest
```

**THEN** update **firebase.json** to

```
"runtime": "nodejs10"
```